# Create log file using php

Tags: php, logfiles

I am creating a back office website , and need to trace the operations done on the website , for that I need a to generate a log file of every operation 
for example : Date-Time -User-Operation.
I have tried files but did not really work

```
$query_add="UPDATE auth_table SET etat = replace(etat,'$anc','$nv') where user_id LIKE  
'%$log%'";
$query_exec=mysql_query($query_add) or die(mysql_error()); 
?><script language='JavaScript'>alert('Activation termine')</script><?
$date = date("Y-d-m"); 
$heure = date("H:i"); 
$op=$date.$heure.'Activation du compte de'.$log.'par administrateur'.$logad; 
$fp = fopen('log.txt', 'w');
fseek($fp,0);
fputs($fp, $op);
fclose($fp);
```

Any idea on how to do this ?

Comment: Search and you will find starting points: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096470/atomically-appending-a-line-to-a-file-and-creating-it-if-it-doesnt-exist

Comment: @Daryl Gill : I will update the question to show you what I have tried so far.

Comment: alternatively instead of LOG files, why not use DATABASE as a store point of all processes, LOG files are for core applications and not web applications...how do you LOG files people accessing your web?...think about it...or your tags must vb/c++/c#/java ?

Comment: http://www.redips.net/php/write-to-log-file/

Comment: I think I will just do that . thank you

Comment: I would consider using apache on .htaccess http://www.webreference.com/programming/Apache-Logging/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query_add="UPDATE auth_table SET etat = replace(etat,'$anc','$nv') where user_id LIKE  
'%$log%'";
$query_exec=mysql_query($query_add) or die(mysql_error()); 
?><script language='JavaScript'>alert('Activation termine')</script><?
$date = date("Y-d-m"); 
$heure = date("H:i"); 
$op=$date.$heure.'Activation du compte de'.$log.'par administrateur'.$logad;
$op .= "\n";
$file = 'log.txt';
$search = file_get_contents($file);
$check = strpos($search, $log);
if ($check === FALSE) {
  $fp = @fopen($file, 'a');
  $write = @fputs($fp, $op);
  @fclose($fp);
}
```

That would work, assuming `$log` and `$logad` have already been defined.