# PHP file_put_contents not working WITH 777 permissions and Apache permissions

Tags: php, json, apache, permissions, 777

I'm currently trying to use `file_put_contents` to update a JSON file of mine. This is what my PHP currently looks like:

```
$result = file_put_contents('Resources/logs/file.json', $newJsonString);
if($result === true) {
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}
```

However, it always returns `false`. Nevertheless, I have set the directory permissions to 777 for BOTH `Resources` and `logs`. I have also set file permissions to 777 for `file.json`.

The path is also correct, as `file_get_contents` works with the same path from the same file.

To **further** prove my point, I have also ran `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/core/Resources/` to give permission to the directory `Resources` (and everything within) to be written to by the user `www-data` (which I'm assuming would allow the JSON file to be written to by running the PHP script online).

I don't know if this would be helpful, but I'm also running this PHP script by sending `POST` data to it via JavaScript from a different server/website.

Why in the world is `file_put_contents` **STILL** returning false and not writing to the file? It always makes the JSON file blank after it is ran.

**Supplementary Code:**

This is the whole chunk of code, including the `file_put_contents` section:

```
$jsonString = file_get_contents('Resources/logs/file.json');
$data = json_decode($jsonString);
$data->coins = $data->coins + $coins;
$data->uses = $data->uses + 1;
print_r($data);
$newJsonString = json_encode($data);
$result = file_put_contents('Resources/logs/file.json', $newJsonString);
if($result === true) {
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}
```

...and this is the JSON file:

```
{"coins":"0","uses":"0"}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated, I've been trying to fix this issue for one whole day already.

**Edit 1:**

I forgot to mention this, but this code was working perfectly fine yesterday for about an hour. Then all of a sudden it stopped working and started making the JSON file blank.

**Edit 2:**

I have just cleared the Apache error log, and the script it working again (which is good). However, `file_put_contents` is still returning `false`. What is going on...

**Edit 3:**

Thanks to Laurent Wartel I have updated my if statement for `file_put_contents` and it seems like it is no longer returning false.

```
if($result === false) {
    echo "Error";
} else {
    echo "All good, $result bytes written";
}
```

Comment: Take a look in the server error log. Notwithstanding what you've done to release the permissions, that's still the probable cause. The error log will tell you if that's the case.

Comment: Which user is running the PHP process? Probably www-data runs just the HTTP server but not the PHP process.

Comment: @MikeW How can I do that? I'm still extremely new to this realm of server work.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER How can I check that?

Comment: @user3681788 try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7771601/1652031

Comment: The log files are in `/etc/httpd/logs`, or possibly `/var/www/log`.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER The user `www-data` is running the PHP process. However, I have just cleared the Apache error log, and the script is working again. Any idea on why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Try to write a string to your file. This way you can determine if your problem resides on the file writing or the content generation:

```
file_put_contents('Resources/logs/file.json', 'Hello, file');
```

Also, I'd add a LOCK_EX flag to the file write call to make sure you are not running into concurrency issues.

Comment: As of right now, my code is once again working. However, can you further elaborate on `LOCK_EX` and show an example of how it can be used? By concurrency do you mean multiple people using it at once?

Comment: Also, as shown here, does `LOCK_EX` need to be used with `FILE_APPEND`? Because in my code I'm not appending anything, but replacing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479580/is-there-a-risk-in-running-file-put-contents-on-the-same-file-from-different-p#answer-5479596

Comment: LOCK_EX is one of the flags you can add when writing to a file. It can be use along with FILE_APPEND, but it is no necessary. Your write call will look like this: file_put_contents('Resources/logs/file.json', $newJsonString, LOCK_EX); This ensures that you get an error if you try to write to a file that is already been written to.

Comment: Ahh, thank you. And let's say that I do not use the `LOCK_EX` flag, what issues would concurrency provoke? Could that lead to issues like blank files and such?

Comment: It can cause intermittent file write errors quite difficult to debug. I think your problem is that sometimes you are reading the file while it is still being written, trying to json_decode it (I'd also look for errors there), and writting the results (that might be blank) to file.

Answer (score 0):

From the doc [PHP: file_put_contents - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

> This function returns the number of bytes that were written to the
>   file, or FALSE on failure. Warning
>
> This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a
>   non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on
>   Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the
>   return value of this function.

Modify your code...

```
if($result === false) {
    echo "Error";
} else {
    echo "All good, $result bytes written";
}
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you. I've updated my code and it is not returning false.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

This function returns the **number of bytes** that were written to the file, or FALSE on failure.

You can't user the identical comparison operator to check for success. Both of this alternatives are valid:

```
if($result) {
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}
```

or

```
if($result === false) {
    echo "false";
} else {
    echo "true";
}
```